# Ipad orientation problem with modal view

Tags: iphone, ipad, orientation

i've a problem with a modal view rotation.
I create a main view in portrait mode, then i create a modal view. Everything works fine: i can rotate the modal view and all orientation are supported.
If i create the main view in portrait mode *then* rotate in landscape and after that i create my modal view... the modal is in portrait mode and not in landscape as it should be.

Both shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in main view and modal view return YES.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post some example code? How are you creating and presenting your modal view controller?

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if the view controller is being presented after iOS queues a rotate event, but before the rotate event is handled. From observation, I think rotate events are specific to the view controllers currently being presented.

This is a helpful way of thinking of it:

1. The rotate event is queued up by iOS for the top view controller, A.
2. Your code presents a view controller, B.
3. The rotate event is dequeued, but it addresses only view controller A.

Thankfully, there's a really easy fix. Just assume there's a rotate event in the event queue, and make sure your view is actually presented *after* it. You do this by queuing the presentation of your new view controller, rather than presenting it directly. Blocks queued to the main queue will be executed *after* any events already queued (like rotate events) but *before* the user gets a chance to interact with your UI.

Change:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"firstRun" sender: self];
```

To:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"firstRun" sender: self];
});
```

After doing this, you get this behaviour instead:

1. The rotate event is queued up by iOS for the top view controller, A.
2. Your code schedules the block that will present the new view controller.
3. The rotate event is dequeued, but it addresses only view controller A.
4. The new view controller, B, is presented by your block. It gets the new orientation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I finally worked around it by displaying the modal view from my main view controller (and not from a view controllers of one of the subviews).

Comment: Not much code to share, it's all about the view controller that you call PresentModalViewController on.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, finaly fixed delaying the modal for a second, so the 'parent' view controller could get the correct orientation.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(presentLogin) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0]
```

presentLogin looks like:

```
- (void) presentLogin {
LoginVC *loginVC = [[LoginVC alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];
nav.modalPresentationStyle =UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:NULL]; 
}
```